# Remove certain parts of a webform based on selection from Drop Down List

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I want to be able to be able to include and exclude parts of a form based on what type of request the user selects from a drop down list, also included on the form. Here is my current code. I can make the text boxes disappear but I can't make the labels disappear too.

```
<div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <font color="red">*</font>MAC Request Type:
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlMACRequestType" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlMACRequestType_Change">
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Select One" Value=""></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Add Device" Value="Add Device"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Change Device" Value="Change Device"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Delete Device" Value="Delete Device"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Alert Change" Value="Alert Change"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Other" Value="Other"></asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkbxLiveSearch" runat="server" Visible="false" Checked="true" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="chkbxLiveSearch_Change" Text="&nbsp;Use Live Search"  /> 
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <font color="red">*</font>Device:
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtDevice" runat="server" MaxLength="255" width="375" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <font color="red">*</font>Interface:
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtInterface" runat="server" MaxLength="255" width="375" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

Someone recommended I use an asp:label, but how would I add my red asterisks as well? They are important for the project. This is something that someone suggested, but isn't working as expected.

```
<asp:Panel Visible="false">
                <td>
                    <font color="red">*</font>Device:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtDevice" runat="server" MaxLength="255" width="375" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
                </asp:Panel>
```

Comment: Can you use `<asp:Label>` for your labels? That would give you a server side control that you could use similarly to your TextBoxes.

Comment: I saw your edit. Could you encapsulate all that needs to be hidden within an `<asp:Panel>` and hide just the panel instead of each individual control?

Comment: Will try, and report back.

Comment: I tried the panel, but it doesn't disappear when I do this.... (It was a mess, I will change show you in the original post.)

Comment: Make sure you at least include `runat="server"` on the panel. And if you plan on hiding/showing it from your codebehind, I recommend giving it an ID as well.

Comment: It worked, post an answer so I can give you internet points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to hide the label, create an `<asp:Label>` for it. This will give you the server side functionality similar to your `<asp:TextBox>`.

To make things even easier, I will often lean towards the use of an `<asp:Panel>`. This is essentially a server side `<div>` and gives you the ability to hide many things all at once rather than hiding all of them individually.

This also won't leave a bunch of empty table rows and cells all over the place.

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlDevice" runat="server">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <font color="red">*</font>Device:
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtDevice" runat="server" MaxLength="255" width="375" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
    </tr>
</asp:Panel>
```

Then just hide the panel like other controls.

```
pnlDevice.Visible = false;
```